# Display price attributes on backend list Magento 2

Tags: attributes

We have a module that create quotes that very simaler like create orders from backend, add customer, add product/s by select them so you can see them as a list in the backend before you create the order and submit them.

I tried to add more 2 attributes with price value, I can see them under any product on backend with their value. But when I want to see them in the list on backend I got 0$ instead the value of the attribute.

I added to code :

```
<strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Extra Price 1: ')); ?></strong>

<?php $pricingHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data::class); ?>
<?php echo $pricingHelper->currency($product->getData('price_tier_1'), true, false); ?>
<br />

<strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Extra Price 2: ')); ?></strong>

<?php $pricingHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data::class); ?>
<?php echo $pricingHelper->currency($product->getData('price_tier_2'), true, false); ?>
```

any idea why? suggest to solve it and see the correct value that appear in the product information in the backend?

Thanks!

[image]
Here is all the code that i used (phtml) and the js script part that Hamendra Sunthwal suggested, and it still not show up the value in salesrep_approval_tier_1 / salesrep_approval_tier_2 attrbites.

```
<?php
    $item = $block->getItem();
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $tierItem = $item->getTierItem();
    ?>

    <?php $block->setPriceDataObject($item->getTierItem()); ?>
    <?php if ($block->displayPriceExclTax() || $block->displayBothPrices()) : ?>
        <?php  ?>
        <?php if ($block->displayBothPrices()) : ?>
            <span class="label"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Excl. Tax')) ?>:</span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $block->displayPriceAttribute('original_price'); ?><br /><br />
        <strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Approval Tier 1: ')); ?></strong>

/** This is the script that I added - but still it is not show me the value in attrbute 'salesrep_approval_tier_1' */
        <script type="text/javascript">
           require(["jquery"],function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
               var dividprice1= $('salesrep_approval_tier_1').val();
                                $('salesrep_approval_tier_1').val(dividprice1);
               });
            });

         </script>
/** This is the end of script that I added */
    <br />
    <strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Approval Tier 2: ')); ?></strong>
/** In this soultion - it is show me 0$ instead the value in 'salesrep_approval_tier_2' attribute */

    <?php $pricingHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data::class); ?>
    <?php echo $pricingHelper->currency($product->getData('salesrep_approval_tier_2'), true, false); ?>

/** This is the end to show 'salesrep_approval_tier_2' attribute */

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($block->displayPriceInclTax() || $block->displayBothPrices()) : ?>
        <?php if ($block->displayBothPrices($block->getStore())) : ?>
            <br /><span class="label"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Incl. Tax')) ?>:</span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php echo $block->displayPrices(
            $block->getBaseOriginalPriceInclTax($tierItem),
            $block->getOriginalPriceInclTax($tierItem)
        ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getIsSelectedTier() && $product->hasTierPrice() && !empty($product->getTierPrice())) :?>
        <a id="quote-view-advanced-pricing-hover" class="quote-view-advanced-pricing-hover">advanced pricing</a>
            <div id="quote-view-advanced-pricing" class="quote-view-advanced-pricing" hidden>
                <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Advanced Pricing')); ?>
                <ul>
                    <li><?php echo __('Catalog price: %1', $block->formatPrice($product->getPrice())); ?></li>
                    <?php foreach ($product->getTierPrice() as $advancedPrice) :?>
                        <li>
                            <?php echo __(
                                "Qty %1: %2",
                                (int)$advancedPrice['price_qty'],
                                $block->formatPrice($advancedPrice['price'])
                            ); ?>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: List on backend ? In backend product grid ?

Comment: if you go to Sales>orders>Create new order > sign user > add product to order and the list there... I saw it call "data-table admin__table-primary order-tables"

Comment: I added print screen from Quote but it is very simler to orders...

Comment: Try this <?php echo $pricingHelper->currency($product->getPriceTier1(), true, false); ?>

Comment: If still doesn't work and if only these two attributes are needs to be shown above , use jQuery , get value from the two div below and display in above div.

Comment: still show 0$... I think need to configure the fuction somewhere to get the fuction getTier1...

Comment: Yep , Or use jquery if you just want to display those value there.

Comment: I would like to just add these 2 parameters to this page... I am not familer with jquery...more idea how to do that?

Comment: Posted answer of this question

Answer (score 1):

Add this js code in the phtml file in  which is called in the above page and replace div id and it will work.

`require(["jquery"],function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
           var dividprice1= $('#dividprice1').text();
           var dividprice2= $('#dividprice2').text();
//Div id where you want to show price one           $('#dividpriceone').val(dividprice1);
//Div id where you want to show price two           $('#dividpricetwo').val(dividprice2);
        });
    });`

Comment: Try and let us know if its helpful and works , give upvote on the answer if it works 4 you, so it will help to others in Magento community.

Comment: Hi Hamendra, Thanks, but still not get the value, now is show empty not 0...

Comment: Hi Hamendra, I added all the code (phtml) to the last part of my question with the js

Comment: The idea is to show the values that I have in salesrep_approval_tier_1 and salesrep_approval_tier_2 attributes...   Big Thank in advance

Comment: Yes it will show salesrep_approval_tier_1 and salesrep_approval_tier_2 attributes values into the two div's above.  This code will take values from those two div and render them into the two div which are above. Let me know it if works for you.

Comment: If still doesn't work then , apply the updates answer.

Comment: Hi Hamendra, still not work, please see all the code that I added in the end of my question. maybe I have issue how I add the script to code, as I said I don't familar with my js script. it still not show up the value in salesrep_approval_tier_1 / salesrep_approval_tier_2 attributes.

Comment: Actually you need to correct this code         /Here you need to add the div id or class(in bracket after $ sign )in which the attribute value is rendering properly    var dividprice1= $('salesrep_approval_tier_1').val();
                                //here you need to mention the div id or class where you need to render the value $('salesrep_approval_tier_1').val(dividprice1);
               });